# Is it possible that the word "mislead" has "that clause"?

Tags: clauses

> Suppose we know that Paula suffers from a severe phobia. If we reason
> that Paula is afraid either of snakes or spiders, and then establish
> that she is not afraid of snakes, we will conclude that Paula is
> afraid of spiders. However, our conclusion is reasonable only if
> Paula’s fear really does concern either snakes or spiders. If we know
> only that Paula has a phobia, then the fact that she’s not afraid of
> snakes is entirely consistent with her being afraid of heights, water,
> dogs or the number thirteen. More generally, when we are presented
> with a list of alternative explanations for some phenomenon, and are
> then persuaded that all but one of those explanations are
> unsatisfactory, we should pause to reflect. Before conceding that the
> remaining explanation is the correct one, consider whether other
> plausible options are being ignored or overlooked. The fallacy of
> false choice **misleads** when we’re insufficiently attentive to an
> important hidden assumption, **that the choices which have been made
> explicit exhaust the sensible alternatives.**

Question 1) I don't understand the grammatical structure of this bold sentence. is it possible that the word "mislead" has "that clause"?

I know the word "mislead" is used as below case.

From Cambridge Dictionary
mislead + someone

meaning : to cause someone to believe something that is not true:

example) He has admitted misleading the police about his movements on the night of the murder.

Question 2) Can the word 'exhaust' be used as 'use up' ?

Comment: I think “mislead” is intransitive.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mislead

Comment: So, What is that-clause, in terms of grammatical structure....?

Comment: It’s for “assumption.”

Comment: you mean it is appositive to assumption, right?

Comment: I think it’s a complement and I’m Korean too.

Comment: If the comma after "assumption" were a colon, it would be clearer

Answer (score 3):

What misleads is the stated fallacy, that of false choice.

> **The fallacy of false choice misleads** *when we’re insufficiently attentive to an important hidden assumption, that the choices which have been made explicit exhaust the sensible alternatives.*

The clause that begins with *when* explains what causes the fallacy of false choice to mislead us.
(That it misleads *us* is implied by the clause following *when we're*.)

The phrase *use up* can replace *exhaust*. In this context, it means that you have examined all the sensible alternatives, to be sure that no other possible choice remains.

The final part of the sentence,

> that the choices which have been made explicit exhaust the sensible alternatives.

is an appositive to *hidden assumption*, that is, it is the same thing.

Comment: that the choices which have been **made** explicit exhaust the sensible alternatives. - What does "**made**" mean in this context?

Comment: If I do something,, but don't say why, then my reason isn't known. If I understand and say why I did it, I have MADE my reason EXPLICIT.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make    "5a to cause to be or become...."